# Airflow: sequential task backfill; ignore upstream dependancy

Tags: python, airflow

The airflow set-up I have is Running With CeleryExecutor and Postresql database. I am running production with this setting hence, need the worker and scheduler to run multiple threads at once.

However, I also want to backfill just one task in a date range without affecting the state of anything else in the dag.

This is an example dag:

```
default_args = {
        'owner': 'user',
        'start_date': datetime(2020, 3, 27),
        'depends_on_past': True,
        'wait_for_downstream': True
        }

dag = DAG(
        'test_dag1',
        schedule_interval='00 16 * * *',
        default_args=default_args,
        catchup=False,
        description='Running test_dag1',
)

dummy1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="Dummy1",
        bash_command="echo 0",
        dag=dag
        )

dummy2 = BashOperator(
        task_id="Dummy2",
        bash_command="echo Hello",
        dag=dag
        )

date_task = BashOperator(
        task_id ="date_variables",
        bash_command="echo World",
        dag=dag
        )

dummy1 >> dummy2 >> date_task
```

`airflow backfill test_dag1 -t Dummy2 --reset_dagruns -I -s 2020-03-27 -e 2020-04-05`

The above command will take into consideration the upstream dependancy and run the Dummy1 and Dummy2 for the date range. This run also respects the `depends_on_past=True` and `wait_for_downstream=True` and runs the dags sequentially from start date to end date.

However, I want to ignore the upstream depedency of task Dummy2 and also run the tasks sequentially from the start date to end date.

`airflow backfill test_dag1 -t Dummy2 -i --reset_dagruns -I -s 2020-03-27 -e 2020-04-05`

The above command does not respect the `depends_on_past=True` and runs all the tasks at once, parallely using the CeleryExecutor.

Is there a way to backfill run tasks within a dag sequentially but also ignore the upstream and downstream tasks associated with the Task in question?

Any help would be appreciated.